# Let $F$ be a closed subset of $(X,d)$ and suppose that $\inf\{d(x,z): z \in F\} = 0$ for some $x \in X$. Prove that $x \in F$.

Tags: general-topology

All the limit points of $F$ are contained in $F$ since $F$ is closed. $d(x,z)$ is a set of real numbers. It is obvious that $\inf\{d(x,z): z \in F\} = 0$ for some $x \in X$.

I have no idea how to get started in proving $x \in F$. Any pointers?

I guess I might start: Suppose $x \notin F$. Then $x \in F^c$, the complement of F. Then I might go about showing that the infinum of the set is nonzero.

Comment: Let $x\in X$. Show that if $\inf\{d(x,z):z\in F\}=0$, then $x\in\operatorname{cl}F$, and use the fact that $F$ is closed. \\ Yes, the approach that you just added will work just as well — perhaps even more easily.

Comment: Doing it your way, do we need to start with the definition of infinum?

Comment: Basically, yes: just note that for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there must be a $z_n\in F$ such that $d(x,z_n)<\frac1n$.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using sequences?

Comment: Sure: use your approach. $F$ is closed, so $X\setminus F$ is open. If $x\notin F$, then $x\in X\setminus F$, so there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\cap F=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

if $\inf\{d(x,z):z\in F\}=0$ then we can choose a sequence $z_n\in F$ such that $d(x,z_n)<\frac1n$. It follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n=x$, and as $F$ is closed, that $x\in F$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\inf\{d(x,z):z\in F\} = 0$, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $z\in F$ such that $d(x,z) < \epsilon$. That is, every $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ intersects $F$. So $x$ is in the closure of $F$, which is $F$ as $F$ is closed.

Alternatively, from your standpoint, if $x\notin F$, then as $F^c$ is open, there is an $r > 0$ such that for all $y\in X$, $d(x,y) < r$ implies $y\in F^c$. Thus, for all $z\in F$, $d(x,z) \ge r$. Consequently, $\inf \{d(x,z):z\in F\} \ge r > 0$.

Comment: I can't understand why $d(x,z)\geq r$? Is it using triangle inequality $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ with $d(x,y)<r$? Then, how about $d(z,y)$?

Comment: @MathLearner the open ball $B_r(x)$ is contained in $F^c$, so then $F$ is contained in the complement of $B_r(x)$. Since $z\in F$, then $z$ is outside of $B_r(x)$ and hence $d(x,z) \ge r$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the explanation..